# Javascript add Sign after specific value length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I want to add a sign in an input text field while writing,

if the field extends 20 sign / letters.

How do I accomplish this

So far I tried this:

```
    (function(i){
        $('#input-chapter-name' + i).change(function(){
            if($(this).val().length() > 20) {
                $(this).val($this.val() + '<br>');
            }
        })
    }(i))
```

Thus I get this error in my console:

> Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is not a function(…)

Comment: It looks like you are checking if the input value is less than 20 chars, shouldn't you have something like `if($('#input-name' + i).val().length > 20)`

Comment: Whops I Made an edit

Comment: You have tried calling `val().length()` when it should be used as a property like this `val().length` that might resolve your recent error.

Comment: `$this.val()` doesn't look right either it should be `$(this).val()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Create something like this:

HTML

```
<label>+</label><input type="number">
```

CSS

```
input {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
label {
  position: relative;
  left: 15px;
}
```

It'd look something like: [image]

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jshacker/w53kkrh8/

---

What you need is though, css classes so that you can add it when the length increases a certain limit. Follow Ahmed's answer.

---

Also, note while accepting numbers with 20 digits:

There is a problem with number size. JavaScript numbers cannot be 20 digits in length. You have to use strings to represent big numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the input value length not the element length:

```
(function(i){
        if($('#input-name' + i).val().length > 20) {
            $('#input-name' + i).val($('#input-chapter-name').val() + '<br>');
        }
    }(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a generic implementation, it will add/remove a class on the field according to the current length

### HTML

```
<input type="text" warn-max-length="20" />
```

### JavaScript

```
$(function(){
  $('[warn-max-length]').on('change', function() {
     var $this = $(this);
     var max = $this.attr('warn-max-length');

     // toggle 'max-length-exceeded' class
     $this[$this.val().length >= max ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('max-length-exceeded');
  })
})
```

#### Highlights

- Use `on input` instead of `keyup/keydown` event listener to handle copy/paste cases
- Manage the UI changes in CSS if possible i.e `input.warn-max-length { color: red; }`